# Error 404 when uploading php CodeIgniter files on server

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, production

I have uploaded in production my website files in PHP made on the framework CodeIgniter. Though I changed the .htaccess files and its dependencies (config, etc.), still I have an error 404 as if the server could not access the controller file. This is my first try to put a site in production, any idea ?

---

### .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

### Canonicalize codeigniter URLs

# If your default controller is something other than
# "welcome" you should probably change this
RewriteRule ^(welcome(/index)?|index(\.php)?)/?$ / [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index/?$ $1 [L,R=301]

# Removes trailing slashes (prevents SEO duplicate content issues)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

# Enforce www
# If you have subdomains, you can add them to 
# the list using the "|" (OR) regex operator
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|subdomain) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.tld/$1 [L,R=301]

# Enforce NO www
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.tld/$1 [L,R=301]

###

# Removes access to the system folder by users.
# Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
# previously this would not have been possible.
# 'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

# Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
# such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
# request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

```
# Without mod_rewrite, route 404's to the front controller
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

---

### config.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

$config['base_url'] = 'http://mywebsite.com';
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
$config['url_suffix'] = '';
```

Comment: please provide more details to the problem. For instance your code and the path you're trying to upload to.

Comment: Please provide some code and your path. That would help us help you.

Comment: Is mod_rewrite active on the server? If yes, make sure the .htaccess file has the Options -Multiviews +FollowSymlinks directive and you're allowed to override options.

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure your base_url() function?
It's in config.php file. If it's empty, it assumes taht you are working with localhost, so you have to put your domain there.

Go to config.php and find this line:

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

and put your domain there.

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://YOURDOMAINHERE.com';
```